# Relations with 4 tables [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, relationships

I have 4 tables:

```
projects: id, text
comments: id, text
comment_project: project_id, comment_id
project_group: project_id, user_id
```

My goal is to take all commets and user details for some project.

Currently I am able to get all comments for projects like this:

```
class Project extends Model {

    public function comments(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment','comment_project');
    }
}
```

and in controller I do like this:

```
$comments = Project::find(1)->comments()->get();
        return $comments;
```

Any idea how to take only comments and user details for selected project if  `project_id` and `user_id` exists in `project_group` table?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set another relation method for project_group in your Model, then you should be able to get this like so:

```
$comments = Project::with(['comments','project_group'])
    ->whereHas('project_group',function($q){
        $q->whereNotNull('user_id');
        $q->whereNotNull('project_id');
    });

dd($comments);
```

Model:

```
class Project extends Model {

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','comment_project');
}


public function project_group(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\project_group','comment_project'); // < make sure this is the name of your model!
  }

}
```

Try this:

```
$comments = Project::whereHas('groups',function($q){
         $q->where('project_id',1);
     })->whereHas('comments', function($q){
         $q->where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('project_id',1);
     })
     ->get();

return $comments;
```

Comment: which method I should set? Could you provide me more details? :)

Comment: I would need more details from you for that first. @VladimirDjukic Is project_group a one to many with a foreign key to Project?

Comment: Every project can have more then one user and every user can have more then one project... it is many to many

Comment: I think your comments() method is wrong and should be $this->hasMany(...). Project is the main Model, isn't it? @VladimirDjukic

Comment: I don't understand your `project_group()` method why you link it to `comment_project` table? Why `hasMany()` I has pivot table...

Comment: I just need to display all comments for specific project if user is related to project inside `project_group` table.

Comment: Edited the answer, please try if this gets you the results you need. I changed code in both files. @VladimirDjukic

Comment: You get me idea, please check my answer, how can now display result which I want?

Comment: Does the query you have in your answer do what you want? @VladimirDjukic

Comment: Yes but current problem is I have to many arrays how can I display only comments?

Comment: I hope I get you right, @VladimirDjukic . If you only want to have projects without anything else, above last edit should work

Comment: ahh, now i get it. so why do you have project??? wait a second, I'll try to find it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this, if anyone has better idea pls comment...

Both methods are `belongToMany()`

```
$userCondition = function($q){
                        $q->where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('project_id',1);
                    };

             $commentsCondition = function($q){
                        $q->where('project_id',1);
                    };
             $comments = Project::with(['comments' => $commentsCondition,'groups' => $userCondition])
                        ->whereHas('groups', $userCondition)
                        ->whereHas('comments', $commentsCondition)
                        ->get();
        return $comments;
```